# Map.tryFind returns null instead of None

Tags: cookies, f#

I have the following script.

```
type SetCookie = {
    NameValue : string * string;
    Domain : string option;
    Path : string option;
    Expires : string option;
    MaxAge : string option;
    Secure : bool; // ? no associated value, anything better than bool
    HttpOnly : bool; // ? no associated value, anything better than bool
    }

let GetCookie str =
    let allkeyvalues =
        str.Split ';'
        |> Array.map (fun str ->
            match str.Split '=' with
            | [| key |] -> (key.Trim(), "")
            | [| key; value |] -> (key.Trim(), value)
            | _ -> failwith "there's more than one '='; the format is incorrect.")
    let namevalue = allkeyvalues.[0]
    let attributes =
        Seq.skip 1 allkeyvalues
        |> Seq.map (fun (key, value) ->
            (key.ToLower(), value)) // attribute names are case-insensitive
        |> Map.ofSeq
    {
        NameValue = namevalue
        Domain = Map.tryFind "domain" attributes
        Path = Map.tryFind "path" attributes
        Expires = Map.tryFind "expires" attributes
        MaxAge = Map.tryFind "maxage" attributes
        Secure = Map.containsKey "secure" attributes
        HttpOnly = Map.containsKey "httponly" attributes
    }
```

However, the function call

```
GetCookie "XXX=YYY; path=/"
```

returns null for `Domain`, `Expires`.... and all other option type instead of None. According to the documentation, it should return None if not found? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353538.aspx

```
  {NameValue =
    ("XXX", "YYY");
   Domain = null;
   Path = Some "/";
   Expires = null;
   MaxAge = null;
   Secure = false;
   HttpOnly = false;}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The F# `None` value is actually represented by a .NET `null`. This shows up in cases like this where you print it out in a generic way, but is otherwise just a representation detail. You can actually get this behaviour for your own discriminated unions by annotating a union case that has no arguments with [`CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370528.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The F# specification states that `None` is represented using `null`:

> **5.4.8 Nullness**
>
> **Types with null as a representation value. These types do not permit
> the null literal but use the null value as a representation.**
>
> For these types, the use of the null literal is not directly
> permitted. However, one or all of the “normal” values of the type is
> represented by the null value. The following types are in this
> category:
>
> Any union type that has the
> Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue)
> attribute flag and a single null union case. The null value represents
> this case. In particular, null represents None in the F# option<_>
> type.